# How to pass arguments into a Rake task with environment in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rake

I am able to pass in arguments as follows:

```
desc "Testing args"
task: :hello, :user, :message do |t, args|
  args.with_defaults(:message => "Thanks for logging on")
  puts "Hello #{args[:user]}. #{:message}"
end
```

I am also able to load the current environment for a Rails application

```
desc "Testing environment"
task: :hello => :environment do 
  puts "Hello #{User.first.name}."
end
```

What I would like to do is be able to have variables and environment

```
desc "Testing environment and variables"
task: :hello => :environment, :message do |t, args|
  args.with_defaults(:message => "Thanks for logging on")
  puts "Hello #{User.first.name}. #{:message}"
end
```

But that is not a valid task call. Does anyone know how I can achieve this?

Comment: Can you please update to accept inger's newer answer.

Answer (score 121, accepted):

#### TLDR;

```
task :t, [args] => [deps]
```

#### Original Answer

When you pass in arguments to rake tasks, you can require the environment using the :needs option. For example:

```
desc "Testing environment and variables"
task :hello, :message, :needs => :environment do |t, args|
  args.with_defaults(:message => "Thanks for logging on")
  puts "Hello #{User.first.name}. #{args.message}"
end
```

Updated per @Peiniau's comment below

As for Rails > 3.1

```
task :t, arg, :needs => [deps] # deprecated
```

Please use

```
task :t, [args] => [deps]
```

Comment: Note that the most current docs describe the `:needs` method this way: "That format is still supported for compatability, but it is not recommended for use." (I mention this only for future browsers, since it suggests that eventually `:needs` won't be supported any longer. The section is called "Deprecated Task Paramaters Format"...)

Comment: Bug in that code: puts "Hello #{User.first.name}. #{:message}" ... this does not print "Thanks for logging on", just "message". Fix: #{args.message} for the last substition.

Comment: As for Rails 3.1 'task :t, arg, :needs => [deps]' is deprecated.  Please use 'task :t, [args] => [deps]' instead.

Comment: To clarify the previous comment with an example, I believe this would work out to `task :hello, [:message] => [:environment] do |t, args|`.

Comment: Additional clarification: to pass multiple arguments, `task :hello, [:message1, :message2] => [:environment] do |t, args|` works, and to invoke use `rake hello['message #1','message #2']`. Warning: I found that rake would fail if the argument list contained any clear text, e.g `rake hello['message #1', 'message #2']` (note the space after the comma).

Answer (score 414):

Just to follow up on this old topic; here's what I think a current Rakefile (since a long ago) should do there. It's an upgraded and bugfixed version of the current winning answer (hgimenez):

```
desc "Testing environment and variables"
task :hello, [:message]  => :environment  do |t, args|
  args.with_defaults(:message => "Thanks for logging on")
  puts "Hello #{User.first.name}. #{args.message}"   # Q&A above had a typo here : #{:message}
end
```

This is how you invoke it (http://guides.rubyonrails.org/v4.2/command_line.html#rake):

```
  rake "hello[World]"
```

For multiple arguments, just add their keywords in the array of the task declaration (`task :hello, [:a,:b,:c]...`), and pass them comma separated:

```
  rake "hello[Earth,Mars,Sun,Pluto]"
```

Note: the number of arguments is not checked, so the odd planet is left out:)

Comment: This answer should be the accepted one.

Comment: Man...rake always feels so un-rubyish to me.  Most things in ruby your first guess is how it actually works.  This syntax is just bizarre.  </rant>

Comment: I agree it's definitely no rubbish (<-sorry for the unusual syntax-) Seriously, I see your concern but IMHO it's just a limitation of Internal DSLs: you cannot completely freely redefine the syntax but it's still pretty amazing how far you can go(despite not being a lisp). BTW, what do you think a more intuitive API/DSL would look like for the above purpose?

Comment: This is the correct answer for Rails 3.2.

Comment: To send 2 arguments, 
    task :hello, [:arg1, :arg2]  => :environment  do |t, args|

Comment: To send 2 arguments, without spaces between [:arg1,:arg2]

Comment: @hbin are you saying space after comma breaks it? That would be Ruby bug I guess, and quite a blatant one IMHO .. which implementation/version is it?

Comment: @inger I mean if u want to execute the rake with two args, u shouldn't put any spaces between them. [:args1,**here without any spaces and immediately following the sencond arg**:args2].

Comment: @inger Here are the outputs when I execute the rake.
$ rake webp:convert["hello", "world"]
rake aborted!
Don't know how to build task 'webp:convert[hello,'
/home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/bin/ruby_noexec_wrapper:14:in `eval'
/home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/bin/ruby_noexec_wrapper:14:in `<main>'
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
$ rake webp:convert["hello","world"]
hello
world

Comment: @hbin Ah so this was when you invoked rake not the declaration within the Rakefile(which ChaseT.'s comment referred to).. Yep, in that case shell rules, so you either write the thing as one shell-word(no space) or quote the spaces, or use quotes around the whole thing like `rake 'webp:convert["hello", "world"]'` .. Warning: I haven't tried this one now, but it should work.

Comment: Because I keep forgetting it: Hi myself with bad memory, here is your reminder from yourself of how to pass in these arguments to the call: 
rake something[arg1, arg2]

Comment: @Houen - good point, as a reminder for myself, just added this to my answer:)  note, your comment has a space between args - this breaks it my experience.

Comment: This is good, but escaping or quoting the brackets with `zsh` is a lot of trouble. I ended up using @Dogweather's approach with the environmental variables

Answer (score 61):

Just for completeness, here the example from the [docs](http://rake.rubyforge.org/files/doc/rakefile_rdoc.html) mentioned above:

```
   task :name, [:first_name, :last_name] => [:pre_name] do |t, args|
     args.with_defaults(:first_name => "John", :last_name => "Dough")
     puts "First name is #{args.first_name}"
     puts "Last  name is #{args.last_name}"
   end
```

Notes:

- You may omit the `#with_defaults` call, obviously.
- You have to use an `Array` for your arguments, even if there is only one.
- The prerequisites do not need to be an `Array`.
- `args` is an instance of `Rake::TaskArguments`.
- `t` is an instance of `Rake::Task`.

Comment: This explains why `args.empty?` was giving me weird results. `args` looks like a hash, but it's a `Rake::TaskArguments`. So if you want special behaviour when no args are passed, call `#to_hash` or `#to_s` before checking if `args` is empty.

Answer (score 22):

An alternate way to go about this: use OS environment variables. Benefits of this approach:

- All dependent rake tasks get the options.
- The syntax is a lot simpler, not depending on the rake DSL which is hard to figure out and changes over time.

I have a rake task which requires three command-line options. Here's how I invoke it:

```
$ rake eaternet:import country=us region=or agency=multco
```

That's very clean, simple, and just bash syntax, which I like. Here's my rake task. Also very clean and no magic:

```
task import: [:environment] do
  agency = agency_to_import
  puts "Importing data for #{agency}..."
  agency.import_businesses
end

def agency_to_import
  country_code = ENV['country'] or raise "No country specified"
  region_slug  = ENV['region']  or raise "No region specified"
  agency_slug  = ENV['agency']  or raise "No agency specified"
  Agency.from_slugs(country_code, region_slug, agency_slug)
end
```

This particular example doesn't show the use of dependencies. But if the `:import` task did depend on others, they'd also have access to these options. But using the normal rake options method, they wouldn't.

Comment: This is definitely not environment variables! It *is* rake *arguments* even though rake shows it as environment variables. There is a huge concept (and practical) difference! Note that `country=us ruby -e "puts ENV['country']"` is not the same as `ruby -e "puts ENV['country']" country=us` (environment variable in the first versus argument in the second).

Answer (score 13):

While these solutions work, in my opinion this is overly complicated.

Also, if you do it this way in zsh, you'll get errors if the brackets in your array aren't escaped with '\'.

I recommend using the ARGV array, which works fine, is much simpler, and is less prone to error. E.g:

```
namespace :my_example do
  desc "Something"
  task :my_task => :environment do
    puts ARGV.inspect
  end
end
```

then

```
rake my_example:my_task 1 2 3

#=>  ["my_example:my_task", "1", "2", "3"]
```

The only thing you need to keep in mind is that ARGV[0] is the process name, so use only ARGV[1..-1].

I realize that strictly speaking this does not answer the question, as it does not make use of :environment as part of the solution. But OP did not state why he included that stipulation so it might still apply to his use case.

Comment: `:environment` is needed to load Rails application code. And trying it on a Rails app I get: `["my_example:my_task", "1", "2", "3"]
  rake aborted!
  Don't know how to build task '1' (see --tasks)
`

Comment: this is exactly what i was looking for

Comment: @Djunzu:  Yes, the sample arguments I gave were not intended to be real inputs to rake tasks. It was just for sake of illustration.