# rake task with easy interface

Tags: ruby

Right now I can do

```
rake report shipment_id=5

rake report do
  id = ENV['shipment_id]
end
```

However I want to simplify the interace to the user by having

```
rake report 5
```

How do I do that in rake?

Last resort would be to use ruby and then call rake internally but I want to check if I am missing some feature of rake?

Comment: This is pretty close to what you want (but not exactly): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/825748/how-do-i-pass-command-line-arguments-to-a-rake-task/825832#825832

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This could be useful:
[Rails Rake: How to pass in arguments to a task with :environment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1357639/rails-rake-how-to-pass-in-arguments-to-a-task-with-environment)

Although its only for newer versions of rake.