# ActiveRecord::Dirty and Rake

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, rake

I have a Model (let's call it A) in a Rails project that checks an attribute (let's call it a) with the ActiveRecord::Dirty a_changed? function on before_save. I want to be able to save an instance of A in a Rake task, but simply including :environment isn't cutting it--I'm getting a "no method a_changed? defined on A" message in the Rake task. How do I get ActiveRecord to remember about ActiveRecord::Dirty within a Rake task?

Rails version is 2.3.11

```
namespace :some_namespace do
  namespace :some_subnamespace do
    desc "This is a Rake Task"
    task :some_taskname, [:some_arg] => [:environment] do |t,arg|
      foo = A.find(11111)
      foo.save #<=== fails with "no method a_changed? defined on A"
    end
  end
end
```

Since that's a pretty dense bunch of info, here's the breakdown:

1. I have a model A with an attribute a.
2. Model A has a before_save trigger defined that calls a_changed?, which is a method added by ActiveRecord::Dirty in the Rails environment. There are no problems calling this from a controller.
3. In my Rake task, however, the a_changed? call in the before_save trigger causes a NoMethodError exception to be raised, presumably because the [:environment] requirement is not sufficient to include ActiveRecord::Dirty. My question is how to make this not happen (my workaround is to rescue NoMethodError from inside the before_save, which is an obvious hack).

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your question has [already been answered on a previous question asked on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5393324/995874).

In order to determine what methods your object has you can do this:

```
...
desc "This is a Rake Task"
task :some_taskname, [:some_arg] => :environment do |t, args|
  foo = A.find(11111)
  p foo.methods
...
```

This will print out a list of the available methods.  If the array includes `:some_attr_changed?` (where `some_attr` is an attribute), then you can be certain that ActiveRecord::Dirty is indeed working fine in the rake task.  If those methods don't show up in the array, then your assumptions are correct.

Comment: This is nowhere close to what I'm asking for. Passing arguments is easy. It's accessing the blah_changed? ActiveRecord::Dirty method on my model instance that I'm not able to do. I'll see if I can clarify the question.

Comment: Sorry that this wasn't what you're looking for, but your original question made it seem like you were having trouble accessing the syntax.  That being said, there is no need to downvote my response.  Only trying to help.  Also, if you try adding a line to your task that like this: `p A.ancestors`, you will see that the class does indeed inherit from `ActiveRecord::AttributeMethods::Dirty` and `ActiveModel::Dirty`, so clearly it is inheriting the methods from these modules.  I was trying to be helpful.  I just tried the same case you have here and it worked fine for me.

Comment: Thanks, sorry about the downvote, I just wanted to bring it back to neutral and I don't really know the conventions here.