# Rake task on Heroku: STDIN.gets.strip - "Enter" key behaves as pressed twice

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, stdin, enter, rake-task

I made an interactive rake task to do administrative job. This task gets input through `STDIN.gets.strip` and locally behaves as planned: I enter some value, press `Enter` and the task runs further stopping at next `STDIN.gets.strip`.

But when I attempt to run it on Heroku through `heroku` gem (in Windows 7):

```
heroku run rake admin --app my-application
```

it recognizes the `Enter` key as pressed twice - the first time with value, the second time as just `Enter`, without value.

How to prevent this behaviour? Could I clean the input buffer in some way right after `STDIN.gets.strip` ?

Answer (score 0):

Personally I think this is the wrong approach.

it would be better to simply define your rake task to take command line parameters and then you do not need to deal with the hassle of interactive input

See this Question for more details

[Rails Rake: How to pass in arguments to a task with :environment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1357639/rails-rake-how-to-pass-in-arguments-to-a-task-with-environment)

Comment: I know how to make the task which takes arguments and have several tasks of such kind, but I do not like this approach out of following reasons: 1. each rake task prepares to run loooong period of time and then does the job quickly. I am annoyed. The interactive task allows me to do in 20 seconds things the 10 rake tasks do. These 10 rake tasks take up 2 minutes (including waiting); 2. I have to list rake tasks with rake -T (and wait until it begins to list tasks actually). I have to remember each task's calling syntax.

Comment: P.S. Mark, I was asking about STDIN in an interactive rake task, but you answered that I do not need an interactive rake task. In a strict conditions I would have to downvote your answer, but will not do this actually.

Comment: Hi paul, i appreciate your comment, one thought though, if the task in question that needs input only takes 20 seconds to complete could you not create an interface for that input in your web site, have a web page that takes the input then run the task processing. 20 seconds would not blow out the 30 second limit on Heroku.

Comment: Hi Mark. Unfortunately the user management should not be available through web-interface. That is a customer's requirement.